# Help creating an Android app to access Tomcat Server?

Tags: java, android, rest, ant, tomcat6

I am interested in creating an application to perform management tasks in Apache Tomcat.
I have seen there are a large section of ant Tasks that can help with most of these tasks, but I am not familiar with how to run ant tasks in my code.

Can anyone help me find a resource to understand how to use these tasks, or another way I can get access to the Tomcat Management console.?

I would prefer to have REST Api access if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ant tasks probably won't be a good solution, as ant is generally used to help build and install applications.

But, you can use something like the `HostManagerServlet` to do some of the management tasks in Tomcat.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/manager/host/HostManagerServlet.html

It may be best to just try and access this directly, as it is a servlet, so urls are how you access it anyway.

Security will be your larger concern, I expect.